# How can you prevent Permissions Problems when Restoring a Windows Machine with Rsync?

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, cygwin

When restoring files (using rsync over cygwin) from Linux to Microsoft Windows XP (and probably to all version of windows), each file restored has permissions so strict, that only the "SYSTEM" account may access these restored files.

I know how to change the permissions, but I'm looking for a solution that makes rsync-restored files inherit permissions of the parent folder to which the files are sync/restored. Or, simply modifies the files without changing their current permissions on the windows machine. Or something similar **that ultimately restores the files in a manner in which I don't have to manually adjust permissions after each restore / sync**.

Comment: I think this would be better-suited on Server Fault...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the rsynch process run under the "administrator" user it will normally be ok.
I Use delta copy under windows and set the deltacopy service to run as administrator also granting the administrator run as a service rights.

This solves the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Well, I'm actually doing this from a windows client-side service, using c#'s System.Diagnostics.Process object. The windows service is logged in as an administrator, but that alone isn't solving the problem.